# Payment option for shopping cart application iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, storekit

I have been working on an shopping cart app for a retail store. They want us to enable payment option within the application. Using Paypal SDK its available in 4.1 and above but I heard it's not allowed by Apple. But I need to use it in iOS 3.0 onwards.

Is their any other way to enable payments within application other than in-app purchase? I want to use it in iOS 3.0 onwards. Is their any solution to use it in iOS 3.0 and above.

Comment: Thanks Guys, It was really great to work on paypal. I got it working on 3.0 also. Just changed targeted OS to 3.0